# how to use lift json2.6.2 remove field by name?

Tags: lift-json

use `removeField` can filter `JFiled` by name at 3.0M8 version.How about 2.6.2? It not have that method and `remove` method not catch name.

Answer (score 0):

```
JValue.transform{
  case JField("sid", x) => JField("sid", JString(x.values.toString))
}
```

I find this way, seems great!